# organic chemistry and magnet

Tags: organic-chemistry, magnetism

Is it possible to use magnet to influence the reaction in order to favor one outcome over the other? ie addition reaction that favor the minor.

Comment: In short, it is not. Some reactions can be influenced by the magnetic field, but the effect is minuscule anyway.

Comment: Magnetic fields have been used to effect short-lived radical ions pairs generated via photoinduced eletron transfer reaction. But this was in spectroscopical studies only. I'm not aware of any use in preparative organic chemistry.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301462204003965